# (C#) How do I stop Increment and decrement jumping around place values?

Tags: c#, integer, operators, increment, decrement

For some reason this code makes the numbers jump around in place value.

For an ex.

If I add the numbers up to up to 10 when I subtract one time it will change to 90 if I subtract again it goes to 80.
If I start adding again 90 turns into 01...

So somewhere in my code I must be telling it to do this...

I have tried a few different things but the same thing keeps happening.

```
int x;
int y;

Console.WriteLine("X:" + (x=0) + "Y:" + (y=0));

//Change Coordinates
while(true){
  ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
  Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop -1);
Console.WriteLine("X:"+x +"Y:"+y);

if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow){

    y=y+1;
 }
else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow){

        y=y-1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
Console.WriteLine($"X:{x,2} Y:{y,2}");
```

You were not printing y for a start. But your main problem was that you were leaving old characters in the line once you had got to 2 digits. THis forces the output to be always 2 digits wide

Comment: That was a typo on here. I am printing y in my actual code however. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Also, what does $ mean in C#. I tried looking it up and could only find it being used but not mentioned why it was being used.

Comment: @ParthOrthrix its called string interpolation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated